# How to automatically update public key for third party repository

Tags: apt, updates, repository, gnupg, keyserver

I have Embedded Linux devices and also I host a third-party repository created with reprepro and signed with GPG key. The myrepo.list inside the devices look like this

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/myrepo-archive-keyring.gpg] https://repository.example.com xenial main"
```

The problem that I am facing is that the key have expiration date and I don't know how to set the devices to update the key before it expires. It will be not possible to take all devices back, so it has to be done automatically.
I have one idea: To create script with cronjob to periodically download the key that will be hosted somewhere in the repo

`wget -q https://repository.example.com/files/apt-key.gpg -O /usr/share/keyrings/myrepo-archive-keyring.gpg`

Is it possible to do it with gpg and keyservers?

Comment: This is one of the issues that led to the developments of Snaps. While that might not help you with the current set of devices, future devices could be much easier to update. Also be aware that Ubuntu developers are thinking about changing the format of apt sources (your PPA), and eventually deprecating the current format.

Comment: I don''t know much about Snap, but are the packages then available for the public? My repos are for now only private. Do you have some source about the deprecation of apt? will love to read about it

Comment: It came up at DebConf 2022: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X53EjiU8vOk . Merely an FYI, and not really relevant to your actual Question.